# How do i update multiple rows with multiple condition in Code Igniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am just learning PHP and using the `Codeigniter` framework.
I'm using this code in my controller when inserting new data and it's working.

```
//INSERT MULTI ROWS TABEL harga_inventori
    $kode_inventori = $_POST['kode_inventori'];
    $result = array();
    foreach($_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'] AS $key => $val){
        $result[] = array(
                "kode_kategori_pelanggan" => $_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$key],
                "kode_inventori"=>$kode_inventori,
                "harga" => $_POST['harga_jual'][$key],
                "diskon" => $_POST['diskon'][$key]
                );
    }
    $res = $this->db->insert_batch('harga_inventori', $result);
    redirect("inventori");
```

But when I'm using the same pattern for the updating function, it's not working at all.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['harga_jual'][$i]); $i++) {
    if($_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$i] != '') {
        $res[] = array(
                        'harga' => $_POST['harga_jual'][$i],
                        'diskon' => $_POST['diskon'][$i],   
                    );
        $this->db->where('kode_inventori',$_POST['kode_inventori']);
        $this->db->where('kode_kategori_pelanggan',$_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$i]);
        $this->db->update('harga_inventori',$res);
    }
}
redirect("inventori");
```

I'm trying the `update_batch()` but I got many errors, so I'm using `for` loop and updating a single row at a time.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `$res` !== `$data`

Comment: for `[update_batch](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch)' you can't use `where` in query. You just have to pass column name in  third parameter and that name parameter should be exist in update array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , still doesn't working. i already change it

Answer (score 0):

Its only a typo. You should pass the array `$res` not `$data`, and change `$res[]` to `$res` since it is not needed. You should also check with `isset()` to prevent errors of undefined:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['harga_jual'][$i]); $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$i])) {
        $res = array(
                        'harga' => $_POST['harga_jual'][$i],
                        'diskon' => $_POST['diskon'][$i],   
                    );
        $this->db->where('kode_inventori',$_POST['kode_inventori']);
        $this->db->where('kode_kategori_pelanggan',$_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$i]);
        $this->db->update('harga_inventori',$res);
    }
}
redirect("inventori");
```

It would help to see some of your data to know what you are trying to do. It seems a little strange that you initiate the counter `$i` at the same time using it as an array key in the for loop like this: `for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['harga_jual'][$i]); $i++)`

It would help to know how the data in your `$_POST` looks like. You could try to remove the `[$i]` in your for loop. I would also check each POST variable it they are set before using them, something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['harga_jual']); $i++) {

    if(isset($_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$i])) {

        // CHECK IF POST VARIABLES IS SET AND IF NOT SET A DEFAULT VALUE (IN THIS EXAMPLE AN EMPTY STRING):
        $harga_jual = isset($_POST['harga_jual'][$i]) ? $_POST['harga_jual'][$i] : ''; 
        $diskon = isset($_POST['diskon'][$i]) ? $_POST['diskon'][$i] : '';          
        $kode_inventori = isset($_POST['kode_inventori']) ? $_POST['kode_inventori'] : '';
        $kode_kategori_pelanggan = $_POST['kode_kategori_pelanggan'][$i]; // ALREADY CHECKED ISSET ABOVE...

        $data = array(
                    'harga' => $harga_jual,
                    'diskon' => $diskon,   
                    );

        $this->db->where('kode_inventori',$kode_inventori);
        $this->db->where('kode_kategori_pelanggan', $kode_kategori_pelanggan);
        $this->db->update('harga_inventori', $data);
    }
}
redirect("inventori");
```

Comment: Please update your question with your current code thats not working.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.
i got sick last weekend.
I just change the code.